# Shell mod operator return quotient

Tags: shell

The mod operator returns the remainder.
For example:

```
>> echo $((31 % 5)) 
>> 1
```

Is there any way to get the quotient (= 6) out of this?
Or is there any alternative way get the quotient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply this :

```
echo $((31 / 5))
```

You can't get the quotient with `%`